# Bluemix Devops and Cast iron Containers

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, devops

I want to use Devops pipeline for building and deploying Castiron orchestrations in Castiron containers. How can i create the Castiron container through devops pipeline.

Do I need to upload the cast iron docker image into GIT repository and configure the build and deploy stage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to first upload cast iron docker image.
Steps in this [link](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_pipeline_ov.html#container_pipeline_ov) might help

Comment: And incase if you want to create image yourself then refer this: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGR73_7.5.1/com.ibm.wci.VAuserguide.doc/CIDC_creating_cic.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally when working with containers, you should be considering the output of any container build as an immutable artefact. And as such an additional stage in your pipeline could be to publish the container to a repository or an artefact repository.

The artefact (container) is then available in subsequent stages within your pipeline. i.e. The container can be pulled down and deployed in a Deploy Stage.

In terms of pushing your container into GIT, you can do that directory within a script or with the Bluemix DevOps Service GUI.

Documentation on how you can achieve with just Bluemix DevOps Sevice:
IBM Developerworks: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/d-bluemix-devops-pipeline-trs/index.html

I would however recommend looking into an actual artefact repository (such as Artifactory). Register a custom service using the CF (Cloud Foundry) CLI to your Bluemix account, then utilize that service when you are required to store/retrieve a container(s).